How can I tell stryker to be ok with test/suite names?
I'm just getting started with StrykerJs and it's mutating my suite and test names and calling that a mutation survival.  For example, I have a test (in Vitest if it matters):
test('should return the command module if it is valid', async () => {
  // test things
});

and a Stryker run gives me:
[Survived] StringLiteral
scripts/src/core/dynamic-loader.test.ts:61:7
-       test('should return the command module if it is valid', async () => {
+       test("", async () => {
Ran all tests for this mutant.

I understand that a test will pass if the name is changed.  What I don't understand is what I'm supposed to do to fix this?
